# Unlock Unisoc bootloader on Linux

Tags: fastboot, linux, bootloader-lock

I need a Linux command to unlock my **Unisoc bootloader** using modified fastboot.

The command `./fastboot devices`  keeps telling me permission is denied.

```
joseph@penguin:~/modified_fastboot$ ./fastboot devices
-bash: ./fastboot: Permission denied
```

<sup>[Screenshot of terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5k3Xi.png)</sup>

Comment: The permission denied is a message from Linux. Make sure to properly configure your Linux system (whatever distribution you use) to be able to access Android devices via USB. Hopefully you are talking about a real Linux system, not a Linux on Windows (WSL).

Comment: by coincidence someone posted this today on xda (don't know what it is, maybe spam) https://unisoc-android.github.io/subut

Answer (score 0):

- Temporary fix: run the command as root

  ```
  sudo ./fastboot devices
  ```
- Permanent fix:

  1. use `lsusb` to identify your device USB VendorID
  2. configure `udev` to set proper permissions when your device is plugged in

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28127944/12075599